# How can I show Fibonacci identity?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

How can I Show a Fibonacci identity: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}F_{k}F_{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k+1)F_{k+1}(-2)^{n-k}$$
Can anyone help me, i have no idea.

Comment: There are always things you can do when you don't know how to tackle a problem; see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933.

Comment: I got a different formula : $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}{F_{k}F_{n-k}}=\frac{\left(n+1\right)F_{n-1}+\left(n-1\right)F_{n+1}}{5} $$

Answer (score 0):

You may use the ordinary generating function of Fibonacci numbers:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}F_n x^n = \frac{x}{1-x-x^2} \tag{1}.$$
Letting $[x^m]\,g(x)$ be the coefficient of $x^m$ in the Maclaurin series of $g(x)$, we have
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} F_k F_{n-k} = [x^n]\left(\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}\right)^2\tag{2} $$
and
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}(k+1)F_{k+1}(-2)^{n-k} = [x^n]\frac{1}{1+2x}\left(\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}\right)' \tag{3}$$
so the LHS and RHS are different things.

Comment: @JackDAurizio: Here we assume initial values $F_0=F_1=1$.